# How does my JSON array need to be formatted to iterate through this $.each?

Tags: php, json, ajax

I need to iterate through data that get via JSON with this code:

```
setInterval(function() {

        console.log("running");
        $.ajax({
            type     : 'get',
            url      : 'data.txt',
            dataType : 'json',
            success  : function(response) {

                console.log(response.bookings) // returns undefined

                $.each(response.bookings, function(index, booking) {
                    sc.status(booking.seat_id, 'unavailable');

                    console.log(booking.seat_id); // returns nothing

                });
            }
        });
    }, 3000); //every 3 seconds
```

The data is currently formatted like this:

```
[{
  "bookings": [
    {
      "seat_id": "1_4"
    },
    {
      "seat_id": "4_2"
    }]
}]
```

But that doesn't seem to be working. What is the correct format that I need to use? I tried a ton of options but can't get it working.

UPDATE:

The error I now get in the console is:

```
jquery-1.11.0.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at Function.each (jquery-1.11.0.min.js:2)
    at Object.success ((index):145)
    at j (jquery-1.11.0.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-1.11.0.min.js:2)
    at x (jquery-1.11.0.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.b (jquery-1.11.0.min.js:4)
```

and line 145 is:

`$.each(response.bookings, function(index, booking) {`

Comment: Your data in a single array of values, not an object. While `index, booking` will working, `booking` would only contain `2_6` and `1_7`.

Comment: @aynber Thank you for the reply. I updated the code with what I think is almost correct but it still doesn't work. I can't figure out what's wrong. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution. Thank you to everyone who helped. It's pretty simple and stupid. I only had to change the JSON response from:

```
[{
  "bookings": [
    {
      "seat_id": "1_4"
    },
    {
      "seat_id": "4_2"
    }]
}]
```

to

```
{
  "bookings": [
    {
      "seat_id": "1_4"
    },
    {
      "seat_id": "4_2"
    }]
}
```

Basically get rid of the `[]`

Answer (score 0):

You have options here. key value {"key":value} or {"name":john} is one way. You can do more info like "employee":{ "name":"John", "age":30, "city":"New York" }

Comment: Thank you; I updated the code above with a sub-array of ``bookings` and then each `seat_id` but it still doesn't seem to work. Do I maybe also need to include something else?

Answer (score 0):

as you said I think you are `response.bookings` array like this `$arr = [1,2,3,4,5];`.

if you iterate like below

```
$.each($arr,function(i,k){
  console.log(i,k)
})
```

you will get output 0,1 1,2 2,3...

but I didn't get booking.seat_id means..? can you give us booking array format?

Comment: Thank you; I updated the code above with a sub-array of `bookings` and then each `seat_id` but it still doesn't seem to work. Do I maybe also need to include something else?